# How to read values from dropdown lists line by line in table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm programming an invoice program. I want to calculate prices row by row. I have a table with rows and columns. A single row consists of 6 columns: "product", "description", "unit cost", "quantity", "vat%" and "total price". VATs can be selected from 4 options in dropdown list.

How to read selected values from dropdown list row by row?

My HTML is like this:

```
<table id="items">
... ... 
... ...
<td><form action="dropdown">
    <select id="dropdown-vat">
        <option value="0">0%</option>
        <option value="10">10%</option>
        <option value="14">14%</option>
        <option value="24" selected>24%</option>
    </select>
</form></td>
... ...
... ...
</table>
```

I did a JS function like this but it works properly only on the first line.

```
function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row'); 
  var e  = document.getElementById("dropdown-vat");

  var vatUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value / 100 +1;  // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
  vatUser = roundNumber(vatUser,2);
  var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("€","") * row.find('.qty').val() * strUser;
  price = roundNumber(price,2);
  isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html(price+"€");
```

The function works properly on the first line.
The price is calculated "cost" * "qty" * "1 + selected VAT"
For example 10 * 1 * 1.20 = 12. // HERE vat is 20% so 1 + 0.2 = 1.2

The problem appears if user adds a second line. 
Then the calculator uses vat from the first line.

If the first line is 10 * 1 * 1.2 = 12, 
Then second line works like this: 10 * 1 * 1.0 = 12. Instead of using 0% (1.0), program uses 20% (1.2, from the first line).

EDIT: 
Function update_price() is called when user changes a cost (blur), a qty(blur) or a vat(click) value.

Comment: How is that function called?

Comment: 1)  cost or qty loses the focus by using blur function
2) or when i choose a vat from dropdown list -> click function

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I recently resolved a similar-ish issue - and why you are seeing what you are seeing.....

You get the number from the first line as JS (and, therefore, jQuery) can only have UNIQUE 'ids', so the second line (with the same id) is never read.

To solve it, use a 'combo' of things - namely, use a class for a common listener, then grab the info on a 'change' function.

```
<select id="dropdown-vat" class="vat">
    <option>..... as you have them </option>
</select>
```

in the script....

```
$(".vat").change(function() {
    var selected = this.selectedOptions[0]);
    // now you can get its value, classes, whatever
    console.log("value of selected is ", selected.val());
});
```

There may be more direct ways to get this, though this worked for what I needed.

The point here is that IDs must be unique, so you could also make a unique id for each line, then process the change (similar to what I have shown).  If you need the id from that line:

```
    var theIdOfTheSelectedLine = selected.id;
```

There is likely a lot more to totally answering the question, though this should help you with the main issue (non-unique ids on elements).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment - if my answer (or another) is correct, please mark it so - if you still need assistance, please edit your question (you can just add to it on the bottom if you want) and I or someone else can help.  Comments aren't really good for doing code and if you will put the code and the issue in your question, it is much simpler to help.

Comment: `$('.vat')[1]` will get the first element matching that selector so will still get the first dropdown! Then you might as will use `this` inside the function

Comment: thanks @yezzz - I originally answered in more of a step-by-step way and put the [1] in to show the OP what was going on - though it did miss the 'second line' point....  I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the value of the select element

```js
var e = document.getElementById("dropdown-vat");
e.onchange = function() {
  // value of e... this or event.target
  console.log(this.value);
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown-vat">
  <option value="0">0%</option>
  <option value="10">10%</option>
  <option value="14">14%</option>
  <option value="24" selected>24%</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: your question is unclear as we don't know what `.item-row` is and we can't see what `a cost (blur), a qty(blur)` is about.

My best guess is that following should work:

First change select to use class: `<select class="dropdown-vat">`

Then, seeing you use jQuery:

```
function update_price() {
  var row = $(this).parents('.item-row'); // the parent table row???
  var vatUser  = row.find(".dropdown-vat").val();

  // etc
}
```

For dynamically added elements you should use delegated event handlers. Assuming your table already created when running js code:

```
$("table#items").on("change", ".dropdown-vat", update_price);
```

Comment: This is similar to what the OP has in the question.  What isn't clearly shown in the original code (but asked in the question) is for a "second line" - i.e., a new row in the table that also has a dropdown - and being able to read that new 'line' selection.  So, the answer is a bit more complex (I also missed that point the first few times I read the question....)

Comment: Ah yeah you're right about that… still you missed the point on how to get the dropdown and its value.

Comment: OnChange function works only for the first row. If I add a new row and try to read vat value from a second row, nothing happens.

Comment: That's because your question was unclear and I thought there was only 1 vat dropdown in the table. ID's must be unique so you should use classes instead (as mentioned by CFP Support). Edited my answer… making some assumptions, as your example code was incomplete. Read [mcve]